# Optimizing a loop : huge arrays operations

Tags: performance, matrix, fortran, simd, hpc

I am doing huge calculations (derivatives here, but look similar to images operations) on arrays that do not fit in cache, meaning the CPU have to load parts in the cache, calculate, then load another part, etc. But because of the shape of calculations, some data are load, unload and reload multiple times. I was wondering if there is a way to optimize this. I am already using SIMD instructions using the compiler optimization (GCC and Intel).

This is Fortran calculations, but it's similar to C/C++, the memory order is just inverted and arrays use `()` instead of `[]`. `for` is replaced by `do`.

On x axe:

```
   do k=1,N(3)
      do j=1,N(2)
         do i=3,N(1)
            DF(i,j,k)=(F(i+1,j,k)-F(i-1,j,k))*B+(F(i-2,j,k)-F(i+2,j,k))*C
         end do
      end do
   end do
```

On y axe:

```
   do k=1,N(3)
      do j=1,N(2)
         do i=3,N(1)
            DF(i,j,k)=(F(i,j+1,k)-F(i,j-1,k))*B+(F(i,j-2,k)-F(i,j+2,k))*C
         end do
      end do
   end do
```

on z axe:

```
   do k=1,N(3)
      do j=1,N(2)
         do i=3,N(1)
            DF(i,j,k)=(F(i,j,k+1)-F(i,j,k-1))*B+(F(i,j,k-2)-F(i,j,k+2))*C
         end do
      end do
   end do
```

First derivative on axe x is OK because memory is read continuously. Derivatives on y and z axes are not continuous.

And the worst calculation I have combine all axes (This is a Laplacian operator):

```
 do k=1,N(3)
    do j=1,N(2)
       do i=3,N(1)
          V(i,j,k) = M(i,j,k,1) * p(i,j,k) &
                 & + M(i,j,k,2) * p(i-1,j,k) &
                 & + M(i,j,k,3) * p(i+1,j,k) &
                 & + M(i,j,k,4) * p(i,j-1,k) &
                 & + M(i,j,k,5) * p(i,j+1,k) &
                 & + M(i,j,k,6) * p(i,j,k-1) &
                 & + M(i,j,k,7) * p(i,j,k+1)
       end do
    end do
 end do
```

Note that compilers do not understand the last operation (Laplacian). To use SIMD (vectorized calculations), I need to split the operation like this, which gives a 2.5x speedup:

```
 do k=1,N(3)
    do j=1,N(2)
       do i=3,N(1)
          V(i,j,k) = M(i,j,k,1) * p(i,j,k) &
                 & + M(i,j,k,2) * p(i-1,j,k) &
                 & + M(i,j,k,3) * p(i+1,j,k)
       end do
    end do
 end do
 do k=1,N(3)
    do j=1,N(2)
       do i=3,N(1)
          V(i,j,k) = V(i,j,k) + &
                 & + M(i,j,k,4) * p(i,j-1,k) &
                 & + M(i,j,k,5) * p(i,j+1,k)
       end do
    end do
 end do
 do k=1,N(3)
    do j=1,N(2)
       do i=3,N(1)
          V(i,j,k) = V(i,j,k) + &
                 & + M(i,j,k,6) * p(i,j,k-1) &
                 & + M(i,j,k,7) * p(i,j,k+1)
       end do
    end do
 end do
```

Maybe using SIMD I already reached maximum speed, but because these calculations takes days, even with MPI and more than 1024 CPU, reducing the time of calculations, even of 20% would be a great step!
Does anyone of you have ideas on how to optimize this?

Comment: Have you tried loop tiling?

Comment: @FUZxxl the op stated he is ok with the answer written in C. This is about the algorithm. Does he have to rewrite the examples for that ? (it is trivial).

Comment: @VladimirF That's not how tagging works. There is a policy (usually regarding C/C++ questions) that a question should not say “pick a programming language” as it happens all too often that the suggested solution is not applicable to the programming language OP actually wants to use.

Comment: @FUZxxl OK, so oxedions, You have to re-write every example in C and in C++ and then you can apply the C and C++ tag. Or even better post three separate questions for Fortran C and C++ and hope someone will note close it as as a duplicate. Welcome on SO. (I really can't see what would not be applicable here, we could even just use pseudocode)

Comment: @VladimirF It happens quite often. For example, I write a solution using variable length arrays. These do not exist in C++. Or maybe (for this example) I'm going to use some C extensions that aren't available in Fortran or C++ like this, etc. etc. C, C++, and Fortran are all different languages. Tell us which one you are using and we can give you an answer.

Comment: @FUZxxl In HPC it is extremely common to cover both C and Fortran in ine course notes, in one presentation, in one textbook. You just rewrite the syntax! Should I give you some examples?

Comment: @VladimirF Yes, that does work in simple cases. OP specifically asked for optimization and optimized algorithms may no longer exhibit this property. Please understand the difference between “there are C programs that can be expressed equally in Fortran” and “all C programs can be expressed equally in Fortran,” the latter of which is a false statement.

Comment: If any tag is superficial, that would be the [mpi] tag. This is clearly a node-level optimisation problem (that applies equally to C and Fortran) and the relation to MPI is very distant.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. In fact the program is Fortran/C/C++. All languages are combined depending of needs, and variable types are totally compatible. For example, here it's Fortran because compilers really like this simple language and optimize it very well. I/O are in C because it's faster, etc. Only few C++ is used, but more and more is written. Thank you for tag modifications.

Comment: If C/C++ can be faster here, then this part of code will switch to C/C++ :-)

Comment: The problem is that much less people can see the question now. So you may want to post the question as a new post in C as well and reference this one and explain that @FUZxxl wanted you to do so.

Comment: @VladimirF If the project is written in Fortran, then tag as Fortran. If it's written in C, then tag as C. Don't tag just because the community is larger.

Answer (score 3):

When you use 3D stencils and you reference elements like `i,j,k-1`, `i,j,k+1` the linear order in which you go through the array will not be optimal. The cache efficiency can be increased by [loop tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling).

In my code I use

```
!$omp parallel private(i,j,k,bi,bj,bk)
!$omp do schedule(runtime) collapse(3)
do bk = 1, Unz, tnz
 do bj = 1, Uny, tny
  do bi = 1, Unx, tnx
   do k = bk, min(bk+tnz-1,Unz)
    do j = bj, min(bj+tny-1,Uny)
     do i = bi, min(bi+tnx-1,Unx)
         U2 (i,j,k) = U2(i,j,k) + &
           (U(i+1,j,k)-U(i,j,k)) * ...
         U2(i,j,k) = U2(i,j,k) - &
            (U(i,j,k)-U(i-1,j,k)) * ...
         U2(i,j,k) = U2(i,j,k) + &
            (U(i,j+1,k)-U(i,j,k)) * ...
         U2(i,j,k) = U2(i,j,k) - &
            (U(i,j,k)-U(i,j-1,k)) * ...
         U2(i,j,k) = U2(i,j,k) + &
            (U(i,j,k+1)-U(i,j,k)) * ...
         U2(i,j,k) = U2(i,j,k) - &
            (U(i,j,k)-U(i,j,k-1)) * ...
     end do
    end do
   end do
  end do
 end do
end do
!$omp end do
```

where `tnx`, `tny`, `tnz` are the sizes of a tile in which you iterate in the `i,j,k` order. The size must be set to be close to the L1 cache. This will increase reuse of the content loaded into the cache.

If you need to separate the directions, you can of course do that and still keep the tiling.

Comment: Hum, very interesting, thank you for this idea ! This makes sense. I will try it on my Haswell without the OpenMP pragma. Using tiling I could also mask asynchrone mpi communications by starting in center of field then expanding. I will try it and share the results asap. I will use gcc 5.2.0 and different levels of compiler optimizations.